# How to update input field from bootstrap modal if field is not empty?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have made a form with dynamic table, and when the form is filled up, on button click, values from all fields will be inserted in one field with comma separated. The problem is that I don't know how to check if field is empty, if it then insert data, else update data in that input field.

This is my html code

```
<table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" name="name"></td>
                <td><button class="remove">-</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" name="name"></td>
                <td><button class="remove">-</button></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <button id="addRow">+ Add</button>
    <button id="getValues">Get Values</button>
    <br/><br/><br/>
    <input type="text" id="myMainPageInput" />
```

And this is jquery

```
var html = '<tr><td><input type="text" name="name"></td><td><button class="remove">-</button></td></tr>';

$(function() {
    $('tbody').sortable();

    $('#addRow').click(function(){
        $('tbody').append(html);
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.remove', function() {
        $(this).parents('tr').remove();
    });

    $('#getValues').click(function(){
        var values = [];
    if ($('input[name="name"]').val().length != 0){
        $('input[name="name"]').each(function(i, elem){
            $("#myMainPageInput").val(($("#myMainPageInput").val() + ', ' + $(elem).val()).replace(/^, /, ''));
        });
     }
    });
});
```

This makes me duplicates everytime when I click on button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of it differently: Since you are checking whether if it's **empty** or **not empty**, and proceed with the logic **in any case** (that's how I understood it, correct me if I'm wrong), then just empty the field entirely before populating it.

```
$('#getValues').click(function(){
    $('input[name="name"]').val('');
    var values = [];
    $('input[name="name"]').each(function(i, elem){
        $("#myMainPageInput").val(($("#myMainPageInput").val() + ', ' + $(elem).val()).replace(/^, /, ''));
    });
});
```